# Why does catkin_make fail when package depends on 'move_base'?

Tags: navigation, catkin-make, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using ROS for a few days and I am following the tutorial for setting up the Navigation Stack.  It tells me to create a package as follows:

```
catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep
```

Since tf and odom are handled in the zen package, and my sensor is a Kinect, my actual command is:

```
catkin_create_pkg zen_2dnav2 move_base freenect_launch zen
```

When I execute catkin_make I get an error due to move_base:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "move_base" with
any of the following names:

  move_baseConfig.cmake
  move_base-config.cmake
```

I googled and subsequently removed the error by:

- Removing the build-Dependency on move_base from package.xml
- Removing move_base from
  find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS ...) in CMakeLists.txt

So my questions in order of importance are:

- Why did I get the error ?
- What are the implications of removing
  the dependency ?  i.e. Will the
  Navigation Stack fail because of this
- During my googling I read that
  move_base is not catkinized and a
  catkin package cannot depend on it.
  Does that mean the tutorial is doomed
  to failure.  I am hoping the
  information is out of date and
  move_base IS catkinized.  How can I
  check this ?  Is there an up to date
  list of packages that work in Kinetic
  ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244769/why-does-catkin_make-fail-when-package-depends-on-%27move_base%27-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Why did I get the error?

You are probably getting the error because the move_base package is not installed in your machine. Try to execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation
```

It will install all the packages you need to run the navigation stack.

> What are the implications of removing the dependency ? i.e. Will the Navigation Stack fail because of this

By removing the dependency your package will fail to compile if it uses any library or header file defined in mobile_base package.

> During my googling I read that move_base is not catkinized and a catkin package cannot depend on it. Does that mean the tutorial is doomed to failure. I am hoping the information is out of date and move_base IS catkinized. How can I check this ? Is there an up to date list of packages that work in Kinetic ?

That information is out of date. The package move_base is indeed catkinized. You can check it by taking a look at move_base's CMakeLists.txt file.

```
roscd move_base
cat CMakeLists.txt
```

You will see that it uses the proper catkin macros.

If you want to see a list of available packages in Kinetic, execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search ros-kinetic
```

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2016-09-30**:
Exactly what I needed on all my questions.  Thank you very much.

I see now that I was trying to setup the navigation stack without actually having installed it. I am amazed I got as far as I did !

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2016-09-30**:
I am glad this solved your issue. If you are happy with the answer, please, mark it as "correct" using the ✅  button. This way people with the same problem can know that this is the correct answer.

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2016-10-02**:
I tried to do something to accept your answer for ages, but couldn't find what to click.  Thanks for the clue.  I was looking where I see 'edit', 'retag' 'close' etc. and had missed that rather understated tick icon.  Now done, and thanks again.